# Does Firefox support enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead")?

Tags: javascript, firefox, npapi

I have written a plugin which queries webpage parameter from FireFox browser using NPAPI, but whenever I tried to query a webpage having iFrames, I'm getting error while trying to query the innerheight from my plugin:

> permission denied to query innerHeight

I thought it would be cross-domain security rerstriction so I thought of running the following JavaScript code from my plugin using `NPN_evaluate()` function before querying information:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
```

My question is does Firefox latest version support this JavaScript and will it allow me to query the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"UniversalBrowserRead"` doesn't work anymore (see [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667312#c3)) and support for `enablePrivilege()` [will be removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546848).

Comment: Is it correct that support for `enablePrivilege` was dropped in FF 17?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I have finally found a direct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13963632/3995261