# UniversalXPConnect permission error in firefox 17

Tags: javascript, firefox, universalxpconnect

I have a small web JS, that copy and inserts some form data to and from the iframe.
But it doesn't work in Firefox 17. I'm using this code:

```
"netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");"
```

What could be wrong? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 7):

It was removed from running on the web with Firefox 17

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bypassing_Security_Restrictions_and_Signing_Code

> Early versions of Firefox allowed web sites to segregate principals
>   using signed scripts, and request extra permissions for scopes within
>   signed scripts using a function called enablePrivelege. These feature
>   was not used much (aside from abuse), and its complexity made
>   performance improvements difficult. Signed script segregation was
>   removed in bug 726125, the enablePrivilege prompt was removed in bug
>   750859, and enablePrivilege itself was nerfed in bug 757046.
>
> EnablePrivilege is disabled in Firefox 15 and will be removed in
>   Firefox 17.
>
> Sites that require additional permissions should now ask Firefox users
>   to install an extension, which can interact with non-privileged pages
>   if needed.

And a discussion on making an extension: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936845

Comment: Why should I create an extension because of a small script on my page? It's a bit stupid. What about any other solution (copy form data from/to iframe form)?

Comment: @PanInkognito I do not make the rules, ask Firefox why they did it. ;) I do not know what you are doing to give you a different solution. Your post lacks details.